# Remove "Previous 1 Next" Shiny DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Since my table consists of two rows, is there any way to remove "Previous 1 Next" below the table?
My code is:

```
output$users <- renderDT(users_data, editable="all", options = list(info = FALSE, lengthChange = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
```

I have removed all other information but I cannot remove this one.

Comment: Did you try `output$users <- renderDT(users_data, editable="all", options = list(info = FALSE, lengthChange = FALSE, searching = FALSE, paging=FALSE))`?

Comment: if you only want the table itself, in options you can use `dom = "t"`

Comment: Read more about the `dom` option [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom).